# What are the limitations of using AppsFlyer for Analytics?

Tags: android, mobile, analytics, appsflyer, appsflyer-android-sdk

I came across AppsFlyer for mobile analytics but then I'm not able to get custom attributes and events. Is it possible to do with AppsFlyer? And what are the other limitations with AppsFlyer?

Comment: Custom attributes and events are the basic functionality of AppsFlyer Mobile Analytics. So yes, this IS possible with AppsFlyer. RE limitations - none that I can think of at the moment. If you're having difficulties using AppsFlyer Mobile SDK, please post further details so this can be addressed (better yet, reach out at support@appsflyer.com to get a more responsive support).

Answer (score 1):

If you need analyse data by your self than you can export raw data by events with **Pull API** by date interval.

You can find here more actual information about limitations: https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207034366-API-Policy

- Every API request is limited to one request every 10 minutes
- Every API request, that queries data for more than 2 days, is limited
  to 24 requests per day per application and to 120 requests per day
  per account
- Aggregated data queries are unlimited in time, i.e. may span from the
  first SDK integration to the present moment

Comment: How does this answer the question? You did not answer the main question whether getting attributes or events is possible

Comment: Answer for main question was Pull API, i updated the answer.